# PHP Natural sort on array of addresses

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Hi I am having a few issues sorting an array.  I make a call to an API and the data I get back is like so

```
array:41 [
  0 => StreetData {#251
    +house: "1 Some Street"
    +street: ""
  }
  1 => StreetData {#236
    +house: "11 Some Street"
    +street: ""
  }
  2 => StreetData {#236
    +house: "4 Some Street"
    +street: ""
  }
]
```

I am trying to do a natural sort so been trying

```
ksort($address->streets);
```

This does not seem to change anything.  What I am after is basically a natural search.  So numbers should be considered first, and then the street.
So for the above, I would expect it to be

```
array:41 [
  0 => StreetData {#251
    +house: "1 Some Street"
    +street: ""
  }
  1 => StreetData {#236
    +house: "4 Some Street"
    +street: ""
  }
  2 => StreetData {#236
    +house: "11 Some Street"
    +street: ""
  }
]
```

As 11 is greater than 4.  This is a pretty vague example, obviously I expect there to be a 2, 3 etc.

So how can I achieve this natural type of sorting?

Thanks

Comment: `ksort` sorts __by keys__ and  __preserving keys__, use `usort` and create a callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need `strnatcmp` and `usort`.

```
<?php
    class StreetData
    {
        public $house;
        public $street;

        public function StreetData($a, $b)
        {
            $this->house = $a;
            $this->street = $b;
        }
    }

    $arr = array(
        new StreetData("1 Some Street", ""),
        new StreetData("11 Some Street", ""),
        new StreetData("4 Some Street", ""),
    );

    function mySort($a, $b)
    {
        return strnatcmp($a->house, $b->house);
    }

    usort($arr, "mySort");

    var_dump($arr);
?>
```